# How can I add a piece of html code to run on every WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have an interesting challenge that I'm coming up short on (I'm not a WordPress plugin developer). I am using a site that has *OptimizePress* as a theme.  *Optimizepress* calls `the_content` many times in building a page.

I want to include a little code snippet in the body of every page.

```
if ( function_exists( "transposh_widget" ) ) {
    transposh_widget(array(), array(
        'title'       => 'Translation',
        'widget_file' => 'flags/tpw_flags_css.php',
    ) );
}
```

That shows a couple of flags and lets you switch languages on the site. So I need a div set to fixed position / 0,0 (I can adjust later for looks) that has that in it.

Other than outputting something in `the_content`, which seems to be the popular way to do this, what is the best way to achieve getting this on every page of a wordpress site?

**Update**

The code below started - here was my final code that output flags only in the top right corner of the site on every page.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Transposh Flags in Header
Description: Embed Transposh Header Code (in Footer of Page)
*/

function insert_my_footer() {
    echo '<div style="display:block; top:30px; right: 50px; position: fixed; color:white;">';
  if (function_exists("transposh_widget")) {
    transposh_widget(array(),
                     array('title'=>'',
                           'widget_file' => 'flags/tpw_flags.php') );
    }
    echo '</div>';
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'insert_my_footer');
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried header.php?

Comment: Or footer.php, perhaps?

Comment: The theme is very difficult to work with, and I don't want to add anything that will break every time the theme upgrades.  Trying to insert it outside the theme.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I'm not at all familiar with transposh_widget, so I don't really know where or when you want this code to run. However, it's easy to make a plugin that adds things to the bottom of a page, so perhaps you could try that.

Here's a basic plugin to get you started:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: html in foot
Description: embed html at the foot of every page
*/

function insert_my_footer() {
  if (function_exists("transposh_widget")) {
    transposh_widget(array(),
                     array('title'=>'Translation',
                           'widget_file' => 'flags/tpw_flags_css.php') );
    }
    echo <<<END_SCRIPT
<!-- This will be inserted at the foot of every page -->
END_SCRIPT;
  }
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'insert_my_footer');
?>
```

To install this plugin, save it in your `/wp-content/plugins` directory (with appropriate ownership and permissions), and then activate it via the Wordpress admin pages.

Comment: That was really helpful. I edited my question to include the final code used.

Comment: Is there a way (using best practices) to add HTML (a styled div) to the header/footer?  Obviously this is great if you want to add something after the footer (non-html) but not for something users need to see.

Comment: @NicholasKreidberg You could use this method to insert HTML if you like, but the standard way to add HTML to the header or footer would be to use a widget. Most themes support widgets in all sorts of places, and a simple text widget can be used to insert static HTML.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage - Great, thanks for the tip!  It sounds like having a widget to support this functionality would probably be the cleanest way to go.  I'll see if I can get lucky with something more simple but good to know I have a fallback.

Thanks again!

Comment: What exactly do the `<<<END_SCRIPT` and `END_SCRIPT` lines do? Doesn't look like PHP syntax?

Comment: @MoritzLost https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc