# Wordpress Plugin that modifies Page Contents

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am new at plugin development and I am having trouble understanding how a plugin interacts with a page. I believe i understand the concept of hooks and filters but i am still unsure on how to modify or insert text onto a page. Is there a hook for that? For example if I had a plugin that simply added a "top" button at the bottom of each page, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19846464/1679849)

Comment: Several ways are possible to achieve this, but there are many other variables, such as where on the page? If you want a button at the bottom of every post for instance you could `add_filter('the_content', 'your_custom_function_to_output_html')`. If you wanted something in the footer you could do `add_action('wp_footer', 'func_output_what_you_want')`

Comment: have you tried using `shortcodes` create a function (which echo what ever you want) and assign a shortcode to that and then call the short code where ever you want.